# django-viewflow how to use SubProcess

Tags: django-viewflow

The `SubProcess` is a pro feature, but there is no documentation on how to use it, is there any working example of using the `SubProcess` node?

Does that mean I can use `SubProcess` to chain up different workflows? How does one workflow pass information to another workflow?

Some code is better than no code, I presume:

```
...
spawn_next_flow = flow.SubProcess(another_flow)
...
```

Comment: There is subprocess sample in the viewflow cookbook - https://github.com/viewflow/cookbook/blob/master/subprocess/demo/order/flows.py

Comment: When you start a subprocess, the main process gets blocked until the subprocess is finished? And when you start N subprocesses, do the N subprocesses all execute concurrently?

Comment: Yep, it's true. btw, for PRO support, it's better to use zendesk.